# Pylint complains about wxPython - 'Too many public methods'

Tags: python, wxpython, pylint

For the following simple [wxPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython) snippets:

```
import sys
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Simple wxPython App")
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def main(argv=sys.argv[:]):
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I always got the warning message *"R0904: 12:MyApp: Too many public methods"* from Pylint. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Related: *[Can inherited public methods be excluded from Pylint's statistics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339042/)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
# pylint: disable=R0904
```

Stick that at the top of the offending class.

On older versions of Pylint, you have to use

```
# pylint: disable-msg=R0904
```

Unfortunately, if you ever upgrade to a more recent version you'll have to write a [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) script to replace all instances of `# pylint: disable-msg` with `# pylint: disable`.

Comment: @Drake: Actually, that's true for an older version of pylint...I'll edit the question to reflect that.