# Can inherited public methods be excluded from Pylint's statistics?

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint keeps reporting an error (`R: 73,0:MyLogging: Too many public methods (22/20)`) for the following code:

```
class MyLogging(logging.Logger):

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass
```

At first I thought it was a bug in Pylint since the `MyLogging` class had exactly 22 lines of code, but then I realized, that it was including all public methods from the base class `logging.Logger` as well, which added 20 to the statistics.

Is it possible to exclude base classes' public methods from Pylint statistics?

PS.: I'm aware I can change `max-public-methods` to a higher number, or add a one-time exception with `# pylint: disable=R0904`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ways, but none of them are good.

This is not configurable: you can check the code in Pylint's *design_analysis.MisdesignChecker*, within `def leave_class`:

```
for method in node.methods():
    if not method.name.startswith('_'):
        nb_public_methods += 1
```

The above code simply iterates over all methods not starting with "_" and counts them as public methods.

Consequently, I see two ways to do what you want to do:

1. fork Pylint and modify this method:

   ```
    for method in node.methods():
        if not method.name.startswith('_') and method.parent == node:
            nb_public_methods += 1
   ```

   `method.parent` - the class node where this function is defined; also in your `leave_class` function you have a parameter `node` - which is the class node.

   Comparing them you can understand if it is the current class or not.
2. disable this rule in the Pylint configuration and create you own plugin:

   ```
    MAX_NUMBER_PUBLIC_METHODS = 3
    class PublicMethodsChecker(BaseChecker):
        __implements__ = (IASTNGChecker,)

        name = 'custom-public-methods-checker'

        msgs = {
            "C1002": ('Too many public methods (%s/%s)',
                  'Used when class has too many public methods, try to reduce \
                   this to get a more simple (and so easier to use) class.'),
        }

        def leave_class(self, node):
            """check number of public methods"""
            nb_public_methods = 0
            print type(node)
            for method in node.methods():
                if not method.name.startswith('_') and method.parent == node:
                    nb_public_methods += 1
            if nb_public_methods > MAX_NUMBER_PUBLIC_METHODS:
                 self.add_message('C1002',
                             node=node,
                             args=(nb_public_methods, MAX_NUMBER_PUBLIC_METHODS))
   ```

   Basically, this implementation is the slightly modified excerpt of *design_analysis.MisdesignChecker* from the Pylint source code.

For more information about plugins, see *[Helping pylint to understand things it doesn't](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/78354)*, and in the Pylint source code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Temporarily I have increased the max number of public methods. I might implement the plug-in idea, when the project is more mature and more devs will work with it.

Comment: Pylint plugin section is a good reference too. http://docs.pylint.org/plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no configuration in pylint allowing to ignore parent methods. You may do what Romanl is suggesting to by pass the problem until the issue I've created for your pb is resolved upstream (http://www.logilab.org/ticket/116963)